# Copying values only into a table

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy data from a table which gets its value using a formula. And i want to paste the values only into a table in another sheet and also have the table resize to fit the contents. But i get an error on this line in the code below:

```
.Resize.Range.Resize (.Range.Rows.COUNT + 1)
```

**Full code**:

```
Dim LastRow1 As Long
Dim s As Long, w As Long

With Worksheets("PlaceHolderDD")
    LastRow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

With Worksheets("KYC Feedback Page 2")
    w = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

For s = 2 To LastRow1
    With Worksheets("PlaceHolderDD")
        .Rows(s).Copy
        Worksheets("KYC Feedback Page 2").Range("A" & w).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues            
        w = w + 1
    End With

    With Worksheets("KYC Feedback Page 2").ListObjects("Table1")
        .Resize.Range.Resize (.Range.Rows.Count + 1)
    End With
Next s
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to allways define and set all of your `Objects`, in your case you can define and set your "***Table1***" Table.

```
' define the Table object
Dim Tbl1 As ListObject

' set the Table object
Set Tbl1 = Worksheets("KYC Feedback Page 2").ListObjects("Table1")

' resize the Table rows count by 1
'Tbl1.DataBodyRange.Resize (Tbl1.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count + 1)

' use another Range for the Resize
Dim R As Range
Set R = Tbl1.Range

' resize the Table rows count by 1
Tbl1.Resize R.Resize(R.Rows.Count + 1, R.Columns.Count)
```

Comment: i get an error(Object doesnt support this property or methd) on this line:

    Tbl1.DataBodyRange.Resize (Tbl1.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count + 1)

Comment: @Richmond on what line ? you didn't write it in your comment

Comment: Tbl1.DataBodyRange.Resize (Tbl1.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count + 1)

error(Object doesnt support this property or methd)